# Delta Time Travel with SQL error extraneous input '0' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 38)

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I am trying to use Time Travel just to see how to use it, but when I run:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI VERSION AS OF 0")
```

It throws the error:

```
ParseException: 
extraneous input '0' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 38)

== SQL ==
SELECT * FROM RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI AS OF 0
--------------------------------------^^^
```

I've tried changing the query to double quotes and placing the version number in single quotes. The really odd thing is that the query returns results when I simply run:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI AS OF")
```

That's just a side note though as I thought that it would fail in parsing. Data I'm using is:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.parquet
https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2021-02.parquet
```

Full code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName('test') \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config('spark.ui.port', '4050') \
    .getOrCreate()

delta_dir = ('./output/delta')
spark.sql('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS RIDES')

spark.sql('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI(
         VendorID long,
         tpep_pickup_datetime timestamp,
         tpep_dropoff_datetime timestamp,
         passenger_count double,
         trip_distance double,
         RatecodeID double,
         store_and_fwd_flag string,
         PULocationID long,
         DOLocationID long,
         payment_type long,
         fare_amount double,
         extra double,
         mta_tax double,
         tip_amount double,
         tolls_amount double,
         improvement_surcharge double,
         total_amount double,
         congestion_surcharge double,
         airport_fee double
    ) USING DELTA
    LOCATION "{0}"
    '''.format(delta_dir)
)

df = spark.read.parquet('yellow_tripdata_2021-01.parquet')

def update():
    spark.sql("""MERGE INTO RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI
    USING load_table
       ON  RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI.VendorID = load_table.VendorID and
           RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI.tpep_pickup_datetime = load_table.tpep_pickup_datetime and
           RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI.tpep_dropoff_datetime = load_table.tpep_dropoff_datetime and
           RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI.PULocationID = load_table.PULocationID and
           RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI.DOLocationID = load_table.DOLocationID 
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (VendorID,
            tpep_pickup_datetime,
            tpep_dropoff_datetime,
            passenger_count,
            trip_distance,
            RatecodeID,
            store_and_fwd_flag,
            PULocationID,
            DOLocationID,
            payment_type,
            fare_amount,
            extra,
            mta_tax,
            tip_amount,
            tolls_amount,
            improvement_surcharge,
            total_amount,
            congestion_surcharge,
            airport_fee) VALUES (VendorID,
            tpep_pickup_datetime,
            tpep_dropoff_datetime,
            passenger_count,
            trip_distance,
            RatecodeID,
            store_and_fwd_flag,
            PULocationID,
            DOLocationID,
            payment_type,
            fare_amount,
            extra,
            mta_tax,
            tip_amount,
            tolls_amount,
            improvement_surcharge,
            total_amount,
            congestion_surcharge,
            airport_fee)
    """)
```

And then I load the files into load_table and run the update. When I run

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, './output/delta')

fullHistoryDF = deltaTable.history() 

fullHistoryDF.show()
```

I can see all the versions there, but just can't figure out how to query a specific version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect - if you're fetching the specific version, then you need to use syntax `VERSION AS OF NNNN`, but you're simply use `AS OF NNNN`. See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html#as-of-syntax) for details.

Update: This syntax will be supported only starting with Spark 3.3 (See [SPARK-37219](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37219) for details) that will be released in the near future.

Comment: Sorry. I was playing around with the syntax to try to get it to work. I've updated the post. It does not work with ```spark.sql("SELECT * FROM RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI VERSION AS OF 0")``` and gives the same error. ```mismatched input 'AS' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 40)

== SQL ==
SELECT * FROM RIDES.YELLOW_TAXI VERSION AS OF 0
----------------------------------------^^^``` Link to a repo with the code if that helps. https://github.com/MichaelShoemaker/66DaysOfData/tree/master/Day5

Comment: what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Running spark.version in my notebook shows 3.0.1

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot that this syntax isn't available yet in the open source spark - see updated answer

Comment: Got it. Thank you SO much @Alex Ott. This was driving me crazy. I'll keep a lookout for the release!

Comment: You can also use Databricks Community Edition - it supports that functionality: https://community.cloud.databricks.com/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again. I just signed up, but it looks like it is just a 14 day trial correct?

Comment: No. Trial is for full version. Community edition is different, but free (with limitations on scale). look for something like “register”, instead of “try”. Although as I see, that form should be different from trial

Comment: You need to click "Get Started with Community Edition" in the page with selection of Cloud provider - it's at the end of the form